# How can I set the size of columns in a JTableBinding?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, column-width

I am creating a GUI program using NetBeans IDE 8.0 and I need to show a table with different sized columns.
Using a `JtableBinding` linked to a MySql table, it shows the contents in a grid having all columns set to the same width.
I would change the **column width** by code, but I noted that for `JtableBinding` there is not a `TableColumnModel`, while I have it in a `JTable` object.

Is it possible to **set a different size** for each column in a **`JtableBinding`**?
Thanks to everyone who gives me a response.

Comment: you will create table structure with your customize column width and then corresponding object will bind jtablebinding  try

Comment: It doesn't work. It seems like JTableBinding does not see changes in JTable, even if I made them before and after the binding. :(

Comment: `I noted that for JtableBinding there is not a TableColumnModel` - I have never used JTableBinding but is seems that you still need a JTable, so you change the TableColumns of the TableColumnModel created by the JTable. This must be done AFTER you have set the TableModel for the JTable.

Comment: *"How can I set the size of columns in a JTableBinding?"*  What's that?  I don't see it listed in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html)..

Comment: @AndrewThompson it is part of the jdesktop. (org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding<E,SS,TS>)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my class realized with JTableBinding. Setting of column width works well.

```
public class TMZeit extends JTable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8639962215280391425L;
    private List<Zeit> list;
    private ResourceBundle bundle;
    private Object[][] columns;

    public TMZeit(ResourceBundle bundle) {
     this.list = ObservableCollections.observableList(new ArrayList<Zeit>());
       this.bundle = bundle;
     this._initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    private void _initComponents() {
       this._initColumns();

     JTableBinding<Zeit, List<Zeit>, JTable> jTableBinding = SwingBindings
        .createJTableBinding(AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ,
            this.list, this);

     for (int i = 0; i < this.columns.length; ++i) {
         ELProperty<Zeit, String> property = ELProperty.create(String
            .format("${%s}", columns[i][1]));
         ColumnBinding columnBinding = jTableBinding
            .addColumnBinding(property);
         columnBinding.setColumnClass((Class<?>) this.columns[i][2]);
         columnBinding.setColumnName((String) this.columns[i][0]);
         columnBinding.setEditable(false);
     }

     jTableBinding.bind();

     for (int i = 0; i < this.columns.length; ++i) {
         this.getColumnModel().getColumn(i)
            .setPreferredWidth((Integer) this.columns[i][3]);
     }
    }

    private void _initColumns() {
    this.columns = new Object[][] {
        { this.bundle.getString("table.column.serno.tooltip"), "serno",
            Integer.class, 30 },
        { this.bundle.getString("table.column.project.tooltip"),
            "project", String.class, 230 },
        { this.bundle.getString("table.column.activity.tooltip"),
            "activity", String.class, 230 },
        { this.bundle.getString("table.column.time.tooltip"), "time",
            Integer.class, 50 } };
    }
 ...
 }
```

Sorry for bad formatting.